# I made a dynamic sub folder using .htaccess, but the browser can't find the images in the root folder

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, rewriting

I made a dynamic folder this way:

```
RewriteRule ^user/(.+)$ index.php?user=$1 [QSA]
```

I want the browser to look in the root folder for images. Currently it looks for them in example.com/user

Comment: Could you please do mention from which URL to which URL you want to redirect kindly do mention in your question, cheers.

Comment: example.com/rqyweriuy should redirect to example.com/index.php?user=rqyweriuy while johnny.png should redirect to example.com/johnny.png, cheers.

Comment: _“Currently it looks for them in example.com/user”_ - that is how resolving relative URLs _works_. The easiest and most common solution, is to refer to your assets with URLs that start with a slash, those are always relative to the domain root.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, its looking for if a uri is NOT ending with `png` format then redirect it to your `index.php` file, in case you have more formats like `.jpg` etc then change following regex from `!\.png$` TO  `!(\.png|\.jpg)/?$`.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##First rule to skip .png files to go to index.php.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.png/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?user=$1 [NC,NE,L]

##Second rule to serve .png files from images folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !images [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.png/?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /images/$1 [NE,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to do this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+)$ index.php?user=$1 [QSA]
```

Thanks for ideas, RavinderSingh13!

Comment: Thanks for sharing answer, is it handling non png files too from going to index.php?

Comment: Could you please check my answer once if that helps you in serving both `.png` and non `.png` files? Kindly do let me know once.